# how to set js path in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic spring boot project structure, in resources this is my folder structure:

```
resources
-> templates
--> static
---> post.js
-> recover.html
```

In my recover html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{static/post.js}" ></script>
```

but content still not loading cause this is not the right path. I've read other similar questions, but I still not understand how to select the right path to post.js

Comment: maybe a duplicate but other answers didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

you should follow this structor:

```
-resources
    --static
        ---post.js 

    --templates
```

and script **src**:

```
<script th:src="@{/post.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```